# Django ListView Page Redirect into custom URL

Tags: django

I'm trying to redirect a page after submitting a post with the object id placed into the urlpattern. Currently it is returning the following error:

> Reverse for 'create_quotation_add_product' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'pk': 43}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_quotation/quotation-id-(?P\d+)/$']

The first view is for the user to input details and submit it into the database. The second view needs to take the data into the url to bring up the submitted object's primary key for use as a foreign key in a separate table.

**Views.py**

```
class CreateQuotation(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = Quote
    form_class = QuoteForm
    template_name='quotations/create_quotation.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
        return ListView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)

        if self.form.is_valid():
            self.object = self.form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.created_by = request.user
            self.object.created_date = timezone.now()
            self.object.save()

            return redirect('create_quotation_add_product', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class QuotationAddProduct(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = Quote_Products
    form_class = QuoteProductForm
    template_name='quotations/quotation_add_products.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
        return ListView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)

        if self.form.is_valid():
            self.object = self.form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.quote_id = Quote.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
            self.object.save()

            self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)

        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuotationAddProduct, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context['form'] = self.form
        context['quote_pk'] = Quote.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['quote_products'] = Quote_Products.objects.filter(
            quote_id=Quote.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        )

        return context
```

The two urls work fine at the moment, I'm having trouble linking the two together.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create_quotation/$', CreateQuotation.as_view(), name='create_quotation'),
    url(r'^create_quotation/quotation-id-(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    QuotationAddProduct.as_view(),
    name='create_quotation_add_product'
    ),
]
```

Is there something I'm not doing properly in the html form?

**quotations/create_quotation.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

      <input type='submit' value='CONFIRM DETAILS'/>
</form>
```

Sorry if the terms I use aren't correct, only started learning recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below reverse method of django for URL

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_quotation_add_product', args=(self.object.pk,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) shortcut, if you want to pass any arguments to the `create_quotation_add_product` url via the `redirect` shortcut method, you should do it like this:

```
return redirect('create_quotation_add_product', pk=self.object.pk, another_key=another_value).
```

The way you do it, refers to the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) built-in function of Django.